# Golang regex replace between strings

Tags: regex, go

I have some strings in the following possible forms:

```
MYSTRING=${MYSTRING}\n
MYSTRING=\n
MYSTRING=randomstringwithvariablelength\n
```

I want to be able to regex this into `MYSTRING=foo`, basically replacing everything between `MYSTRING=` and `\n`. I've tried:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("MYSTRING=*\n")
s = re.ReplaceAllString(s, "foo")
```

But it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

---

P.S. the `\n` is to indicate that there's a newline for this purpose. It's not actually there.

Comment: So, 3 lines with `MYSTRING=foo` is expected here?

Comment: Yes. Basically I want to replace everything between `MYSTRING=` and `\n` with a string of my choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
(MYSTRING=).*
```

and replace with `${1}foo`. See [the online Go regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cDlt1m/1).

Here, `(MYSTRING=).*` matches and captures `MYSTRING=` substring (the `${1}` will reference this value from the replacement pattern) and `.*` will match and consume any 0+ chars other than line break chars up to the end of the line.

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/_E3eX0ueZ85):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

const sample = `MYSTRING=${MYSTRING}
MYSTRING=
MYSTRING=randomstringwithvariablelength
`
func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(MYSTRING=).*`)
    s := re.ReplaceAllString(sample, `${1}foo`)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
MYSTRING=foo
MYSTRING=foo
MYSTRING=foo
```