# Golang Regex match and replace first occurrence after a certain string

Tags: regex, go

Following up on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54795852/golang-regex-replace-between-strings/54795889#54795889) about using Golang's regex to replace between strings. I now have a bit of complexity added to it. Here is what the contexts of my file looks like:

```
foo:
    blahblah
    MYSTRING=*
bar:
    blah
    blah
    MYSTRING=*
```

I need to replace what's between `MYSTRING=` and `\n` with a string of my choice (like previous stated in the original post). I can do that with:

```
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(MYSTRING=).*`)
s := re.ReplaceAllString(content, `${1}stringofmychoice`)
```

But now I need to match and replace only after a certain occurrence. So that the contents of my file can look something like this:

```
foo:
    blahblah
    MYSTRING=foostring
bar:
    blah
    blah
    MYSTRING=barstring
```

`ReplaceAllString` obviously replaces everything, which is not what I want. Is there a way to only match and replace the first occurrence after a certain string?

---

For a bit of background about all of this. I'm trying to write a program to edit the contents of a given `docker-compose.yml` file and its environment variables. I need to edit the environment variable `MYSTRING` differently depending on what service it's listed under. In the example above, the two different services would be `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Do you have to capture `MYSTRING=` and then use a backreference in the replacement pattern? Can you hardcode `MYSTRING=`?

Comment: Yes I can hardcore `MYSTRING=`.

Comment: There [comes a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) when regular expressions are no longer the best solution to a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`ReplaceAllStringFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAllStringFunc) and use a regex like

```
(?m)^bar:(?:\n\s{4}.*)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GgEMnB/1). It will match a `bar` block indented with four whitespaces. Then, after a match is obtained, you may use a regular `ReplaceAllString` on the match.

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/hYdtCMG4ss6):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

const sample = `foo:
    blahblah
    MYSTRING=*
bar:
    blah
    blah
    MYSTRING=*`

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)^bar:(?:\n\s{4}.*)+`)
    re_2 := regexp.MustCompile(`(MYSTRING=).*`)
    s := re.ReplaceAllStringFunc(sample, func(m string) string {
                return re_2.ReplaceAllString(m, `${1}stringofmychoice`)
        })
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Here, the second occurrence is changed in the `bar` block:

```
foo:
    blahblah
    MYSTRING=*
bar:
    blah
    blah
    MYSTRING=stringofmychoice
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I might have worded my question a bit too confusingly. I meant to say that I need the `MYSTRING=*` replaced with `MYSTRING=stringofmychoice` after a **certain** string has appeared, not after it has appeared a certain number of times. In the example above, that **certain** string would be `bar`. I want to find a string, `bar`, and change the `MYSTRING=*` into  `MYSTRING=barstring` after it.

Comment: @thestateofmay That does not change much.

Comment: Would it be possibly to greedily use the matching between `bar` and `MYSTRING=` instead? I'm trying something like `re := regexp.MustCompile("(bar).(MYSTRING=).*")` but it's not working.

Comment: @thestateofmay ``re := regexp.MustCompile("((?s:bar.*?MYSTRING=)).*")``. Not sure what you mean though. If you plan to use it as a 1-regex solution, [watch out](https://regex101.com/r/L3sXFB/1). Since there is no lookahead support, it is difficult to come up with a working and readable regex for this.